# Fuzzing a Go application with libfuzzer: wrong coverage

Tags: go, shared-libraries, llvm, fuzzing, libfuzzer

I'm writing my thesis and would greatly appreciate some input on my current setup.
I want to fuzz a target Go application with libfuzzer and therefore did the following:

I wrote a main package that calls the go function to be tested. 
Code:

```
package main
import "C"
import "$PACKAGE"
func main(){}
//export Fuzz
func Fuzz(data []byte){
 $PACKAGE.Fuzz(data) //actual Fuzzing function, which instruments the function under test  
}
```

A main package is necessary for `llvm-go` to actually build the application as a shared library. The reason I have a double abstraction here is that I want my build pipeline to be compatible with go-fuzz, which uses the "Fuzz" function name as a fuzzing entry point. With my setup I can simply wrap around the code necessary to make use of libfuzzer.

Then I compile the application with `llvm-go`.

Now I have two ways to instrument the Go shared library: either load it dynamically or have it statically linked in my binary. I'll explain my issue using the statically linked code. For that I wrote some fuzzing stub that instruments the Go shared library.

```
// fuzz_target.cc
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "golang-app.h"

extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *Data, size_t Size) {
 void *handle;
 char *error; 
 GoSlice data = {(void*)Data, static_cast<long long>(Size), static_cast<long long>(Size)};
 Fuzz(data);
 return 0; // Non-zero return values are reserved for future use.
}
```

Then compiled it with:

```
clang -g -O1 -fsanitize=fuzzer,address -o fuzz fuzzing-entry_static.cc ../golang-app.so
```

Now, when I run my code I see two issues:

```
master@thesis:~/go-libfuzz$ ./fuzz-static ./corpus/ -timeout=12
INFO: Seed: 2260122321
INFO: Loaded 1 modules   (1 inline 8-bit counters): 1 [0x787f60, 0x787f61),
INFO: Loaded 1 PC tables (1 PCs): 1 [0x565bd0,0x565be0),
INFO:       11 files found in ./corpus/
INFO: -max_len is not provided; libFuzzer will not generate inputs larger than 18061 bytes
INFO: seed corpus: files: 11 min: 450b max: 18061b total: 76971b rss: 51Mb
#12     INITED cov: 1 ft: 1 corp: 1/450b exec/s: 0 rss: 53Mb
#13     REDUCE cov: 1 ft: 1 corp: 1/282b exec/s: 0 rss: 53Mb L: 282/282 MS: 1 EraseBytes-
[...]
#193    REDUCE cov: 1 ft: 1 corp: 1/1b exec/s: 0 rss: 56Mb L: 1/1 MS: 1 EraseBytes-
#65536  pulse  cov: 1 ft: 1 corp: 1/1b exec/s: 21845 rss: 63Mb
#131072 pulse  cov: 1 ft: 1 corp: 1/1b exec/s: 26214 rss: 68Mb
#262144 pulse  cov: 1 ft: 1 corp: 1/1b exec/s: 26214 rss: 79Mb
#524288 pulse  cov: 1 ft: 1 corp: 1/1b exec/s: 27594 rss: 100Mb
#1048576        pulse  cov: 1 ft: 1 corp: 1/1b exec/s: 27594 rss: 142Mb
#2097152        pulse  cov: 1 ft: 1 corp: 1/1b exec/s: 27962 rss: 226Mb
```

The coverage and features do not seem to increase and the memory requirement increases every run. I was able to fix the memory increase thanks to another SO post by adding an environment variable to the fuzzer execution. `ASAN_OPTIONS=quarantine_size_mb=20 ./fuzz-target -timeout=12`

However, probably the main issue is that the actual target is "buried" under two levels of abstraction:
LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput --calls--> shared Go library via main.go, which contains exported Fuzz function (exposed via CGo) which --calls--> Fuzzing function --calls--> target function. 
Please note, however, that each of those functions just hands over the data directly to the next layer without making changes.
What steps can I do to ensure this is working correctly? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Flimzy Thanks for the grammar correction. :) One thing: I chose to write golang on purpose as searching for "go" via Google can lead to weird results. Whereas using the term "golang" is clear. And as it is tagged with "go" here, there is no need to use the "Go" term alone.

Comment: Yes, googling for "golang" makes sense. But there's never a need for that here, as the [go] tag already has you covered.

Comment: Are you aware of https://github.com/dvyukov/go-fuzz ? It can also generate a target for libfuzzer and should make your work a lot easier.